# Контроль числового порядка определенных записей в строках

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Как можно контролировать порядок определенных записей в строках таблице SQL?

Например у нас есть таблица товаров. Если мы добавляем товар, то порядковый номер повышается, если такой товар уже есть. Если мы удаляем товар который есть, то порядковый номер уменьшается. **Как такое сделать?**

**1**.Процедуру с триггерами в MySQL писать?

**2**.Сделать на уровне php?

**3**.Или может быть есть уже какая-то готовая функция в SQL, или способ подобного контроля?

**Вот пример:**

ТАБЛИЦА_ТОВАРОВ -  тут мы уже что то добавили.

```
| порядковые номера | товары |
|-------------------|--------|
| 1                 |ведро   |
|-------------------|--------|
| 2                 |ведро   |
|-------------------|--------|
| 1                 |грабли  |
|-------------------|--------|
| 3                 |ведро   |
|-------------------|--------|
| 2                 |грабли  |
|-------------------|--------|
 и.т.д.
```

ТАБЛИЦА_ТОВАРОВ -  тут мы из того что ранее добавили, убрали   одно ведро. И если мы снова добавим одно ведро, порядковый номер ведра снова будет равен "3". Если еще ведро допустим добавим, после третьего ведра, то порядковый номер нового ведра будет 4.

```
| порядковые номера | товары |
|-------------------|--------|
| 1                 |ведро   |
|-------------------|--------|
| 2                 |ведро   |
|-------------------|--------|
| 1                 |грабли  |
|-------------------|--------|
| 2                 |грабли  |
|-------------------|--------|
```

Comment: Заведите еще одну таблицу <товар, текущее количество товаров> и обновляйте при записи в основную таблицу транзакцией.

Comment: А как вторая таблица узнает сколько там ведер?

Comment: а зачем такой порядок? почему не использовать сквозной? если ради количества, то его можно и так получить; если вдруг будут проблемы со скоростью, тогда при сохранении/удалении одним запросом увеличиваем/уменьшаем общее количество

Comment: Представим что будет веред 1000 , тогда зачем мне их все перебить в операторе цикле, каком-нибудь, если мне понадобиться четко 25 из них.    Например мне нужны ведра с 225 по 250 позиции. А позже понадобятся с 500 по - 525, и не хотелось бы перебирать все позиции .

Comment: ну так и сделаете `...where товары=ведро limit 225, 250`, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: И все? Вроде то что надо. Спасибо. Ну так публикуйте тогда свой ответ, я отмечу Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Триггеры не нужны. Как-то так:

```
insert into ТАБЛИЦА_ТОВАРОВ 
select (select coalesce(max("Порядковые номера"),0)+1 from ТАБЛИЦА_ТОВАРОВ
where "Товары" ='ведро'),'ведро';
```

Вместо ведра в двух местах подставляйте свой товар.